# Requested store is not found Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException site shutting down again and again with this error

Tags: magento2, database

My magento 2.2 is going down again and again when i see log files i see this error

> main.CRITICAL: Requested store is not found {"exception":"[object]
> (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0):
> Requested store is not found at
> public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreRepository.php:109)"}
> []

i have tried

> 1. 
>
> UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
>
> UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
>
> UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';

> 2

Restarted the apache and mysql server

but these solutions are temperory after some hours site is going down again i want a permenet solution to solve this.
Help me to get out of this.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a Magento patch SUPEE-5984, which addresses these kinds of Enterprise Refresh Index problems.
You can find the patch at https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-patches/blob/master/EE1.14/PATCH_SUPEE-5984_EE_1.14.2.0_v1.sh